# multiple email from email service received

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written a trigger to send email. Whenever the trigger is fired i am getting equal no of mails which is equal to no of records retrieved.

Ex - If i am getting 3 records, three times i am receiving email.
Can anybody tell me where i am going wrong -

```
trigger taskEmail on Project__c (after update ) {
    set<String> projName = new set<String>();
    list<Task__c> listTask = new list<Task__c>();

    for(Project__c pro : Trigger.new) {
        projName.add(pro.Name);
    }

    listTask = [SELECT Id,Project_Approval__c,Project_Name__c,Status__c,Task_Executioner__c FROM Task__c WHERE Project_Name__c IN : projName];
    system.debug('11111' + listTask.size());
    EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name='Multiple Tasks'];
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    Set<Task__c> setTaskName = new Set<Task__c>();
    setTaskName.addAll(listTask);
    List<Task__c> finalTsk = new List<Task__c>();
    finalTsk.addAll(setTaskName);


    if(listTask.size() > 0) {
    system.debug('222222' + listTask.size());
        for(Task__c con : finalTsk) {
        system.debug('33333  enter for ');       
        if(con.Project_Approval__c =='Approved' && con.Status__c == 'Open'){
            system.debug('444   enter if inside for '); 
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setTargetObjectId(con.Task_Executioner__c);
            mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            mail.setWhatId(con.Id);
            mails.add(mail);
        }
        system.debug('0000000');

    }

    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have other triggers or workflow that fires on Project__c? Since this is an AfterUpdate trigger, it could fire multiple times and thus create a new email each time it fires.

Comment: BTW, all of the following code is unnecessary: `Set<Task__c> setTaskName = new Set<Task__c>();
    setTaskName.addAll(listTask);
    List<Task__c> finalTsk = new List<Task__c>();
    finalTsk.addAll(setTaskName);` Just use the results of your query, `listTask` instead. Your query won't return multiple Tasks with the same Ids.

Comment: Task is a related list for Project. So Query will return multiple tasks associated with a project.I am worried wht is causing three times to trigger..So i am receiving 3 emails..

Comment: I recognize there can be multiple related tasks. `setTaskName` doesn't pull anything out into a set to reduce the number of tasks sending related emails. What are your debug logs showing? That will tell you how many times the trigger fires on each project update and how many emails it generates. You may need to add a boolean flag that's is set the first time you enter the trigger to prevent recursion.

Comment: Closing this one as your other version has received answsers and appears asked by your real user account here.