# Received multiple email from apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I have written a trigger to send email. Whenever the trigger is fired i am getting equal no of mails which is equal to no of records retrieved.

Ex - If i am getting 3 records, three times i am receiving email. Can anybody tell me where i am going wrong -

```
trigger taskEmail on Project__c (after update ) {
    set<String> projName = new set<String>();
    list<Task__c> listTask = new list<Task__c>();

    for(Project__c pro : Trigger.new) {
        projName.add(pro.Name);
    }

    listTask = [SELECT Id,Project_Approval__c,Project_Name__c,Status__c,Task_Executioner__c FROM Task__c WHERE Project_Name__c IN : projName];
    system.debug('11111' + listTask.size());
    EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name='Multiple Tasks'];
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    if(listTask.size() > 0) {
    system.debug('222222' + listTask.size());
        for(Task__c con : listTask ) {
        system.debug('33333  enter for ');       
        if(con.Project_Approval__c =='Approved' && con.Status__c == 'Open'){
            system.debug('444   enter if inside for '); 
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setTargetObjectId(con.Task_Executioner__c);
            mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            mail.setWhatId(con.Id);
            mails.add(mail);
        }
        system.debug('0000000');

    }

    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
}
```

Comment: Hey Sid, you've just posted the same code and nearly the samequestion as was in this post: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77033/multiple-email-from-email-service-received. What's up??

Comment: oops..i was thinking i am continuing the same post.. Thanks for the notice..

Comment: The one I linked to was posted by @user2542953. Apparently the two of you are one and the same?

Comment: I have closed the other question, as this one has received answers in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Let n be the number of records in the trigger. You add n items to projName here:

```
for(Project__c pro : Trigger.new) { // remember Trigger.new is the collection of records the trigger is firing for
        projName.add(pro.Name);
    }
```

Then listTask has n items as well (assuming uniqueness) because of this query:

```
    listTask = [SELECT Id,Project_Approval__c,Project_Name__c,Status__c,Task_Executioner__c FROM Task__c WHERE Project_Name__c IN : projName];
```

And here, you add a message to mails for each item in listTask:

```
for(Task__c con : listTask ) {    
.
.
.
    mails.add(mail);
}

Messaging.sendEmail(mails); // this sends all the mail objects in mails, which is n
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your for loop iteration variable is task, it will send as many emails as the number of tasks. For example, if you updated one project with 10 tasks under the project, it will send emails 10 times.

You can consider querying project with tasks as subquery. Then iterate over projects and summarize information of all tasks under a project in one email per project.

Also please note that you can send only 10 outbound emails in one apex transaction

Comment: Hi Victor,Can u help me in updating the code with correct one..